# regex vs substring

Tags: regex, xml-parsing, substring

I have a very short xml String passed to my app from another app and I'm only interested in extracting the content between the "level" tags. Which solution is better between these two:

```
String xmlString = 
"<type>
<perm>
<date>99999999</date>
<level>admin</level>
</perm>
</type>";

String level = xmlString.substring(xmlString.indexOf("<level>") + "<level>".length(),
                            xmlString.indexOf("</level>"));
```

or

```
 Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("<level>(\\S+)</level>");
 Matcher m = p1.matcher(xmlString);
 if (m.find()) {
   String level = m.group(1);
 }
```

Comment: The best solution is number three: Use an XML parser.

Comment: this is not really an xml file, not validated, no doctype...and since I have no control over it I'd rather treat is as a string....Xpath was used in the past and would cause "content not allowed in prolog" and "SAX: parse may not be called while parsing" errors, due to this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8047329

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bench-marking this on your own? From what I've read it seems that you generally want to go regex first and if you can't optimize that then try substring. However I'm a little confused why you aren't using something like `XmlObject.factory` to handling your XML parsing. https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.Factory.html

Comment: If it was up to me this string would be an object and not an xml, but since it's not a validated xml and I only need to read one line of it I'd rather treat it as a string, especially since parsing it as an xml caused problems and concurrency issues at high volume. I tested both methods with multiple threads and substring method is slightly faster than regex, both are a lot faster than parsing with Xpath factory though, which proved to be unreliable in the past.

Comment: Then I would go with substring if it performed best for you. To me it seems easier to maintain than the regex so it's kind of the best of both worlds.